# Error to upload entire video file into memory

Tags: python, file, io

I am trying to upload an entire video file into RAM for quick access. i want the file to be as it is without any decoding, etc. I just want to point to a location in RAM instead of remote driver. The file is only 2 GB. I have 128 GB RAM. I need to do frame by frame analysis and readying from a server takes forever.

I thought i would do something like this

```
with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    file_content = f.read() # Read whole file in the file_content string
print(file_content)
```

But I can an error. Is there another way to do it? Like using IO library?

```
In [11]: u = open("/net/server/raw/2020.04.02/IMG_9261.MOV",'r')

In [12]: data = u.read()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-eecbc439fbf0> in <module>
----> 1 data = u.read()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    320         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    321         data = self.buffer + input
--> 322         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    323         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    324         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 31: invalid continuation byte
```

this example uses requests.get, but this works only for HTTP i have a local server I can mount with NFS

```
import requests
from pygame import mixer
import io

r = requests.get("http://example.com/somesmallmp3file.mp3")
inmemoryfile = io.BytesIO(r.content)

mixer.music.init()
mixer.music.load(inmemoryfile)
mixer.music.play()
```

Comment: try opening the file in  `rb` mode rather than `r` mode. The former is for reading bytes from a file and the latter is for human readable text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a 'b' for binary mode should make it work.

```
u = open("/net/server/raw/2020.04.02/IMG_9261.MOV",'rb')
```